# Output PROC MEANS to a file/SAS data table

Tags: sas

In PROC FREQ procedure we can specify an output table in the following terms:

```
    Proc Freq
        DATA=LIB.TABLE_IN
        ORDER=FREQ;

        TABLES FIELD / MISSING OUT = LIB.TABLE_OUT; /* outputs to a SAS data table */
    RUN;
```

How could we do the same with PROC MEANS procedure?

```
proc means data=LIB.TABLE_IN n nmiss;
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you peek at the documentation before asking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways.  The `output` statement sends output to a dataset; you also can use `ods output` as you can with any proc.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  class sex;
  types sex;
  var height weight;
  output out=class_means mean= sum= /autoname;
run;
```

To use `ods output` you need to know the name of the table produced by the proc. You can use `ODS TRACE` to find out what the name of the table is.

```
ods trace on;
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  class sex;
  types sex;
  var height weight;
run;
ods trace off;
```

You'll find it's called `summary`.  So you add `ods output` statement like so:

```
ods output summary=class_means_ods;
proc means data=sashelp.class;
  class sex;
  types sex;
  var height weight;
  output out=class_means mean= sum= /autoname;
run;
ods output close;
```

Finally, `proc means` has an option after I think 9.3 (or maybe 9.22) `stackodsoutput` which changes the format of the resulting dataset to be more tabular, which may be helpful for you.

```
ods output summary=class_means_ods;
proc means data=sashelp.class stackodsoutput;
  class sex;
  types sex;
  var height weight;
  output out=class_means mean= sum= /autoname;
run;
ods output close;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nearly anything you can do with `proc means` that produces output in the listing area can also be produced via `proc summary` as an output dataset, albeit sometimes with slightly different syntax and in a different output format. E.g. this produces the same information as your example, but in a wide table rather than a long one:

```
proc summary data=sashelp.class;
  var _numeric_;
  output out = my_summary n= nmiss= /autoname;
run;
```

Comment: I realized that you can do it with proc means too... thanks!

Comment: `summary` is just a clone of `means` with different defaults in v8+ SAS.

Comment: @Joe Strangely enough this is one of the few bits of functionality I've come across that doesn't seem to be precisely replicated in proc summary.

Comment: @user667489 Why do you say that?  The difference is only that `proc summary` deafults to `noprint`.  `output` works identically in both...  The `wide` table is the default with `stackodsoutput` turned off, I believe.

Answer (score 0):

If you need only N, MIN,MAX, MEAN, and STD, the simple lines below can produce a nice table, here named 'sumTab'. however, if you add NMISS and others, it will be in a wide format.

```
    proc means data = X ; 
        var _numeric_;
        output out = sumTab ; 
    run;
```